# MySQL to InnerHtml Angular 7

Tags: html, css, mysql, angular, typescript

I want to put HTML code that I am getting from the MySQL database into my HTML page. I am using [innerHtml], but the div width is larger than the page max-width. How can I solve the problem?

**CSS**

```
.sonclass {
 display: inline-flex;
 max-width: 1300px;
}

.fatherclass {
  width: 1300px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="fatherclass">
    <div class="sonclass" [innerHTML]="data.html"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: add what you tried

Comment: Hope, you have tried something useful

Answer (score 1):

You could try a `word-wrap: break-word;` on your innerHTML element to break it into a paragraph

You have to remove the `display:inline-flex` for it to work however